# Plotting horizontal 'stacked' histogram with categorical (binary) values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

My dataset looks more or less like this:

```
TRIAL   PARTICIPANT    KEY_PRESSED
1       1              Left
2       1              Right
3       1              Left
4       1              Left
1       2              Right
2       2              Right
3       2              Left
4       2              Left
...     ...            ...
```

What I'm trying to do is to plot, for each participant, a horizontal histogram showing which key they pressed in every trial, but *keeping the trial order* (from 1 to 4) for each participant 
So far I've tried doing this with the following code:

```r
ggplot(data = data_resp, aes(x = PARTICIPANT, y = TRIAL, fill=KEY_PRESSED))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+ coord_flip()
```

Which results in the following plot:
[image: Histogram1 keys pressed]

As you can see, ggplot identifies the two values of `KEY_PRESSED` (`Left` and `Right`) and plots them separately on each bin.

What I need is to plot each `KEY_PRESSED`in the order in which each participant pressed the key, to get something that would look more or less like this:
[image: Histogram2 keys pressed]

Comment: You're tripping me up using the word "histogram". From what you're describing, I don't think that is the type of plot you desire. You'll probably need to use `geom_tile()`

Comment: You're right @OTStats. I didn't know about the `geom_tile()` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to `geom_tile` should do the trick. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

data_resp <- data.frame(
  PARTICIPANT = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 10),
  TRIAL = rep(c(1:10), 4),
  KEY_PRESSED = sample(c("Left", "Right"), 4 * 10, rep = TRUE)
) 

ggplot(data = data_resp, aes(x = PARTICIPANT, y = TRIAL, fill=KEY_PRESSED))+
  geom_tile(color = "white") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>